# How can I add a visual margin on the right of my window?

Tags: alignment, margin

Here is my document; the entire text is on a single line:

[image]

However, I would like it to be not so wide; for example by using `set textwidth=40` and `gq` I get my desired results:

[image]

The problem with this is that it affects the actual contents of the buffer, whereas I want the changes to be just *visual*.

I looked at changing `columns`, but that changes the width of my terminal as well, and this seems like a hack in the first place.

Is there any good way to add a margin to the right side? (The example is slightly exaggerated; in reality I'd want more like 4-5 characters)

Related:

Comment: all those distraction free plugins just create empty windows around the main window (which you usually cannot enter) to have it look like a single window. There is no other possibility as far as I know. I believe there is even an entry in the todo list about a wrapmargin setting. But so far this has not been done yet. (I started working on a patch several years ago, but never really got around finishing it up to be ready for inclusion and I believe the neovim devs have a similar PR open)

Answer (score 1):

I would simply just `:rightbelow vnew` together with `:set wrap` and adjust the windows at will

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find a decent solution that actually rearranges text perhaps you'll be in the market for a way to make the margin stand out visually. I use the *colorcolumn* option.

```
:h 'colorcolumn'
```

> 'colorcolumn' is a comma separated list of screen columns that are
>     highlighted with ColorColumn |hl-ColorColumn|.  Useful to align
>     text.  Will make screen redrawing slower.
>
> The screen column can be an absolute number, or a number preceded with
>       '+' or '-', which is added to or subtracted from 'textwidth'.

I take it to the extreme and color "all" columns right of my textwidth setting with this

```
let &colorcolumn='+' . join(range(1,256), ',+')
```

(I've not had any issues with slow screen redraws but this might not work well with slower gfx configurations.)

Here is an example with a subtle color choice. Color can be changed by changing appropriate highlight: `:highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=4 ...`

[image]